# Label triggers binding Textcolor based on a toggle

Tags: xamarin.forms, label, togglebutton, behavior

I would like to change the the textcolor using label.datatriggers based on a result from another function. 
Also , how can I access each command , I want to perform an action on each tapped .Where exactly can I add this functionality and how , If I use a view model - how can get the result from IsToggle.

```
if(IsToggle)
{
 //do logic 
} else
{
//do logic 
}
```

example

```
    <Label Text="AUTO" HorizontalOptions="Center"
             VerticalOptions="Center">
              <Label.Behaviors>
               <local:ToggleBehavior x:Name="autoToggleBehavior" IsToggled="{Binding Toggled, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
             </Label.Behaviors>
             <Label.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference autoToggleBehavior},Path=IsToggled}" Value="False"

                 <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White"/>
                 <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Gray"/> 
               </DataTrigger>
               <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference autoToggleBehavior},Path=IsToggled}" Value="True"

                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Blue"/>
                 <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/> 
               </DataTrigger>
             </Label.Triggers>
     </Label>
```

This is the behavior

> ```
> public class ToggleBehavior : Behavior<View>
>     {
>         readonly TapGestureRecognizer tapRecognizer;
>
>         public ToggleBehavior()
>         {
>             tapRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer
>             {
>                 Command = new Command(() => this.IsToggled = !this.IsToggled)
>             };
>
>
>         }
>
>         public static readonly BindableProperty IsToggledProperty = BindableProperty.Create<ToggleBehavior, bool>(tb => tb.IsToggled, false);
>
>         public bool IsToggled
>         {
>             set { SetValue(IsToggledProperty, value); }
>             get { return (bool)GetValue(IsToggledProperty); }
>         }
>
>         protected override void OnAttachedTo(View bindable)
>         {
>             base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
>             bindable.GestureRecognizers.Add(this.tapRecognizer);
>         }
>         protected override void OnDetachingFrom(View bindable)
>         {
>             base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
>             bindable.GestureRecognizers.Remove(this.tapRecognizer);
>         }
>         protected override void OnAttachedTo(BindableObject bindable)
>         {
>             base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
>             this.BindingContext = bindable.BindingContext;
>             bindable.BindingContextChanged += Bindable_BindingContextChanged;
>         }
>         protected override void OnDetachingFrom(BindableObject bindable)
>         {
>             base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
>             this.BindingContext = null;
>             bindable.BindingContextChanged -= Bindable_BindingContextChanged;
>         }
>         void Bindable_BindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>             var bobject = sender as BindableObject;
>
>             this.BindingContext = bobject?.BindingContext;
>         }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can get the result from IsToggle.

You could define the event `propertyChanged` of `IsToggledProperty`

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsToggledProperty = BindableProperty.Create("IsToggled", typeof(bool), typeof(ToggleBehavior), false,propertyChanged: OnIsToggledChanged);

    static void OnIsToggledChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var behavior = bindable as ToggleBehavior;
        bool Toggled = (bool)newValue ;

        if(Toggled)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }


    }
```